# Is it okay to have instance-based stores or is there a better way to achieve this?

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I want to have multiple independent stores that actually behave equally. So I have a store as a private Component field. The question is, if this is bad practise or not.

I have added a store as a private property to a instance like so:

```
export class ContainerWithLocalStore extends React.Component<Props> {
    transientStore: TransientStore;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.transientStore = new TransientStore();
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <Downstream ts={this.transientStore} />
        );
    }
}
```

And the downstream container is the classic increment/decrement observer:

```
type DSProps = {
    ts: TransientStore;
}

export const Downstream : React.FC<DSProps> = observer((props: DSProps) => 
<React.Fragment>
    {props.ts.counter}
    <button onClick={()=>{props.ts.increment()}}>+</button>
    <button onClick={()=>{props.ts.decrement()}}>-</button>
</React.Fragment>)
```

In my actual component (home) we have multiple ContainerWithLocalStore:

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ContainerWithLocalStore />
      <ContainerWithLocalStore />
      <ContainerWithLocalStore />
      <ContainerWithLocalStore />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

The example is working as intended, but the question is, if this is an anti-pattern, and should be done differently.

Comment: this seems reasonable to me

Comment: 1. You say that you want to have multiple independent stores and in the same time they are acting equally. What this exactly means? You are asking if you can use just one instead of many? If the store does not care who is calling it and it does not have some internal state based on the callers, just use one instance.

2. No matter if you use one instance or instance per component, you should pass it as a parameter to the component. Current internal initialization brakes one main rule of creating good and testable architecture(dependency inversion principle)

Comment: @AntoanElenkov to 1. I think it is obvious, that the `ContainerWithLocalStore` has internal state which depends on the instantiating object, so I do a proper separation of concerns (correct me if I'm wrong). If I use a large store, where all counters would be tracked, then that store would be way more complex (as it has to keep a map of counters up to date). Mounting and unmounting takes care of the store, thats why I did it this way in the first place. 

2. Can you provide an example how a inversion of dependency could be achieved here? I think, I dont understand your proposal fully.

Comment: @helt, your sentence "I want to have multiple independent stores **that actually behave equally**" confused me. I will write an answer, because comments size is  limited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem working with a store in the component, because this is the proper way for the UI layer to communicate with the business layer.

About your current architecture.

1. As I said in the comments instantiating classes in the component itself(in other words seeing the word "new") is breaking the DI principle. You can see the big picture of your app and decide where to create these external dependencies. For example in some of my apps for every page(widget, block, etc.) all of the dependencies are created outside and passed to it, so this logical piece of code is testable and extensible.
2. > So I have a store as a private Component field. The question is, if this is bad practise or not.

   Why private filed? The store can be passed and used as a prop like in `Downstream` component.
3. Based on point **"3"** and seeing that `ContainerWithLocalStore` is a component which only creates the instance of a store and pass it to `Downstream`. I don't think you really need it.

So, your architecture could be a bit simplified:

```
export type TransientStoreType = {
    counter:number;
}

export class TransientStore   {
    counter:number;
}


type DSProps = {
    ts: TransientStoreType;
}

export const Downstream : React.FC<DSProps> = observer((props: DSProps) => 
<React.Fragment>
    {props.ts.counter}
    <button onClick={()=>{props.ts.increment()}}>+</button>
    <button onClick={()=>{props.ts.decrement()}}>-</button>
</React.Fragment>)

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Downstream ts={new TransientStore()}/>
                <Downstream ts={new TransientStore()}/>
                <Downstream ts={new TransientStore()}/>
                <Downstream ts={new TransientStore()}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with initiating a store instance inside the component, as long as you initiate it once (constructor).